# Simulate a TCP tarpit

Tags: sockets, tcp, cross-platform

I want to simulate test cross-platform connection failures / timeouts, starting with blocking `connect()`s:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket

s = socket.socket()
endpoint = ('localhost', 28813)
s.bind((endpoint))
# listen for connections, accept 0 connections kept waiting (backlog)
# all other connect()s should block indefinitely
s.listen(0)

for i in range(1,1000):
    c = socket.socket()
    c.connect(endpoint)
    # print number of successfully connected sockets
    print(i)
```

On Linux, it prints "1" and hangs indefinitely (i.e. the behavior I want).
On Windows (Server 2012), it prints "1" and aborts with a `ConnectionRefusedError`.
On macOS, it prints all numbers from 1 to 128 and then hangs indefinitely.

Thus, I could accept the macOS ignores the backlog parameter and just connect enough sockets for clients to block on new connections.

How can I get Windows to also block `connect()` attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, the [SO_CONDITIONAL_ACCEPT socket option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/so-conditional-accept) allows the application to have the incoming connections wait until it's `accept()`ed. The constant (`SO_CONDITIONAL_ACCEPT=0x3002`) isn't exposed in the Python module, but can be supplied manually:

```
s.bind(endpoint)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 0x3002, 1)
s.listen(0)
```

It's so effective that even the first connect is kept waiting.

On macOS, `backlog=0` is reset to `backlog=SOMAXCONN`, `backlog=1` keeps all connections except the first waiting.